# First drawImage call to new canvas is slow on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, internet-explorer-9, drawimage

I have found strange behavior in my drawBuffer function that I can't explain or fix, so lets see if someone can help me out.

Basically this function draws a buffer canvas from a image containing several images. In most browsers this works like a charm and creates + fills the buffer canvas in less than a millisecond. But with IE9 i have found that the first time I draw to buffer canvas, it takes about 10 milliseconds. And with that, it really slows my application down, since it should run at 30 fps.

I have proven that only the first draw takes that massive 10 milliseconds. If you run through my code, you notice i have a second drawImage call right after the first one, and this second drawImage call goes through in 0 milliseconds.

```
UiElement.prototype.drawBuffer = function () {

if(!this.bufferCanvas || !this.bufferContext) {
    this.bufferCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.bufferCanvas.width = this.sprite.getWidth();
    this.bufferCanvas.height = this.sprite.getHeight();
    this.bufferContext = this.bufferCanvas.getContext('2d');
} else {
    this.bufferContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.bufferCanvas.width, this.bufferCanvas.height);
}

var image = this.sprite.getImage();
var startx = this.sprite.getStartX(this.spriteFrame);
var starty = this.sprite.getStartY(this.spriteFrame);

var width = this.sprite.getWidth();
var height = this.sprite.getHeight();

this.bufferContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.bufferCanvas.width, this.bufferCanvas.height);
this.bufferContext.drawImage(
            image,
            startx,
            starty,
            width,
            height,
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height
        );

// 2nd draw is here only for debug purposes 

this.bufferContext.drawImage(
            image,
            startx,
            starty,
            width,
            height,
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height
        );}
```

So to sum it up:
Create canvas - 0ms

1st drawImage - 10ms (WTH?)

2nd drawImage - 0ms

Is there any way to stimulate the canvases g-spot so that she would let me draw that fist image there faster?

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into the same problem.

It seems like IE has to reload the images if they arent used often enough... I'm going to try to leave the images attached to the DOM and see if that helps.